# How to get the Shape.STLength() value from JSON

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to get the Shape.STLength() value from a feature returned from a query.

something like

```
var myLength = returnedJSON.features[0].attributes.Shape.STLength();
```

"Shape.STLength()" is actually an attribute name but I'm guessing that the way I have it in my code is making it look like parts of the JSON object. And the () is making javascript think it is a method.

How do I pass the name as a string? I tried messing about with enclosing it with "" but can't get it to work.

Comment: You can write your own length function to iterate over the array of array of ordinates, or you can include the length on the query that generates the JSON.

Comment: @Vince How do I include the length on the query? Also I like the idea of using a function to iterate over the attributes but I still think it would leave me with the problem, how do I extract the attribute name "Shape.STLength()" when javascript thinks the name is actually a function. I guess I could use index or something.

Comment: I ended up doing a conversion to string, JSON.stringify(), and then extracting out the substring I needed but it looks ugly, it only works if Shape.STLength() is the last attribute and I'm sure there are better ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alternative Json notation will work:

```
var myLength = returnedJSON.features[0].attributes['Shape.STLength()'];
```